# How to set Tiny MCE editor in Joomla to auto fill width and height?

Tags: joomla, tinymce

When I insert an image to the Tiny MCE editor at Joomla! backend, I noticed that the inserted img tag don't have width and height param:

```
<img border="0" alt="Fruit" src="/szalafa/images/stories/fruit.jpg">
```

It is very time-consuming to set width and height for every image..
How can I force the editor to autocomplete the image dimensions?

Thanks!

Comment: strange, on my install tinyMCE automatically updates the image sizes. I have tinyMCE v3.2.6 and I don't recall ever customizing it. I have tested this on Firefox v4.

Comment: I have the v3.2.6 too, but doesn't work..
Do you set something in the config?

Answer (score 0):

ya its time consuming to set height and width for every image . I am also gone through this. Then  i prefer to use css to control height and width.I think it will be good to use css to control this.